# fixed length of permutaions cycles

Tags: permutations, stirling-numbers

How much permutations has  only 10  cycles, 
but three of them has length 3 and seven  of them has length 7?

Comment: Can you better describe what you are asking for? I can't understand.

Comment: i do not understand the question...

Comment: How many permutations having exactly ten cycles, three of which have a cycle length of three and seven - length of seven ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is
$$\frac{(2!)^3(6!)^7}{3!7!}\binom{58}{3,3,3,7,7,7,7,7,7,7}=\frac{58!}{3^3 7^7(3!)(7!)}$$
which is an enormous number. The set of 58 elements is broken into 10 disjoint subsets of the indicated sizes, this number is divided by $3!7!$ to account for the fact that the order of the cycles doesn't matter, after which we have to take into account the ordering of the elements within the cycle. There are $2!$ distinct orderings for length 3 and $6!$ for length 7.

Comment: The order of multinomial coefficients does not matter. So why are we dividing by (3!7!) ? Explain, please.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @ztrn If two numbers in a multinomial coefficient are equal, there is an implied ordering on them. For example, consider $\binom{2}{1,1}=2$. This is the number of ways to choose two subsets of size 1 where order matters, but we divide by $2!$ to obtain that there is a unique way to divide the set into two subsets of size 1.